# API to find latest music releases?

Tags: api

I've been looking all over, and I can't find an API that will return information for the albums released that week.

Anyone know of one?

Comment: You can find a categorized list of streaming music APIs here:  http://musicmachinery.com/music-apis/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the itunes store will let you generate an RSS feed for music, including new releases.
here is the link: http://itunes.apple.com/rss?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed http://www.mechanicalnation.com/category/new-album-releases/ that appear to use the Discogs API.
MusicBrainz could probably also be used.